# Самохостирующие приложения .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Не могу никак понять про самохостирующиеся приложения asp .net core. Вот например когда в VS отладку делаешь, там на выбор iis express и как в консоли, это и есть самохостирующее(то что в .exe в директории bin потом валяется)? Также непонятно что как понял до core был придуман OWIN и Катана поверх него дабы разгрузить system.web и самохостирующие сделать приложения, вопрос в том, зачем тогда сейчас Kestrel. Все в перемешку и owin и kestrel(http сервер) ...

Comment: Даже если удастся в этом разобраться, ваш вопрос похож на попытку вылечить симптом, а не причину возникновения вопроса. В чем ваш исходный вопрос? Какую задачу вы решаете? Что вам даст (даже если правильный) ответ на текущий вопрос?

Comment: У вас в голове все перемешалось. OWIN - это спецификация, это не сервер. Katana - это сервер, который реализует спецификацию OWIN. Katana, на сколько я помню - это windows-only решение. Kestrel - это кросс платформенный легковесный веб сервер, он не предназначен работать отдельно, в реальных системах он должен работать в паре другим сервером, который выступает как реверс прокси (например Nginx).

Comment: Многое что вы описали то понятно, но вот конкретно , когда выбираешь в VS не iis express а вкладку с названием проекта и запускается браузер с консолькой -это именно самохостирующее( kestrel) приложение, просто еще в директори  bin .exe файлик появляется. А так вся суть вопроса такова, если есть старый проект asp .net web api (не core) и поступила задача сделать самохостирующюю реализацию, чтобы от iis и его пулов не зависеть, надо же с owin и катаной подружиться?

Comment: @Саша Если в проекте нет специфичных для Windows вещей, то как вариант на Net Core его переписать - в будущем только плюсы будут, как минимум кроссплатформенность.

Comment: Это я все сам прекррасно понимаю, мне нужен конкретный ответ!